# AssertJ `containsExactly` assertion on list with wildcard

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, assertj, unbounded-wildcard

I have a getter returning a List with a wildcard:

```
import java.util.List;

public interface Foo {
    List<? extends Bar> getList();
}
```

Where `Bar` is an other interface.

When I write an assertion with AssertJ like this:

```
assertThat(foo.getList()).containsExactly(bar1, bar3);
```

EDIT: my complete usage is to chain a `usingElementComparator` and to provide a `Comparator<Bar>` to compare the expected `Bar` instances.

```
Comparator<Bar> comparator = createBarComparator()
assertThat(foo.getList()).usingElementComparator(comparator).containsExactly(bar1, bar3);
```

I get this compilation error:

> The method containsExactly(capture#46-of ? extends Bar...) in the type ListAssert is not applicable for the arguments (Bar, Bar)

---

My first solution is to cast the result:

```
assertThat((List<Bar>)foo.getList()).containsExactly(bar1, bar3);
```

Then I get a warning:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List

Warning can be removed with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, but still the cast in the middle do not make the assertion really readable.

---

My second solution is to indicate the value the ELEMENT generic parameter:

```
Assertions.<Bar>assertThat(foo.getList()).containsExactly(bar1, bar3);
```

A little better, but also not that nice (no static import possible, the beginning of the line do not facilitate the readability)

---

I guess I am looking for an other `assertThat` method for list, where the class type can be specified as second parameter:

```
@CheckReturnValue
public static <ELEMENT> ListAssert<ELEMENT> assertThat(List<? extends ELEMENT> actual, Class<ELEMENT> c) {
    return AssertionsForInterfaceTypes.assertThat(actual);
}
```

This way I should be able to write something like this:

```
Assertions.assertThat(foo.getList(), Bar.class).containsExactly(bar1, bar3);
```

Answer (score 2):

That used to work with the Oracle JDK 7 compiler but this was actually a bug in the compiler, this has been fixed in Java 8 JDK so having the compilation error is the normal behavior (can't find the bug reference though).

I would be happy to support but I'm not sure this is possible in AssertJ except by removing all generics usage in collections assertions.

[`assertThat(List, Class)`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#assertThat-java.util.List-java.lang.Class-) already exists but for another purpose so no luck for that option.

A possible hack is to define your own `assertThat` method like that:

```
public static <T> ListAssert<Object> assertThat(final List<T> list) {
    return Assertions.assertThat(list);
}
```

The trick being to return a `ListAssert<Object>`.

Although I understand the rationale of the compilation error I disagree with it for read only method.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Do not remove all generics usage in collection assertions. They are 95% correct and helpfull.

Returning a `ListAssert<Object>` is not working for me, because I also use a `usingElementComparator`method in the chain (see updated question). I might go with own `assertThatListOf(Class, List)`

By the way, *THANK YOU* for AssertJ, It is a great library!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, appreciated.